# Boto3 add security group to EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I create instances like so:

```
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name="eu-central-1")
client.run_instances(ImageId="ami-0df63501d4a3233e8", MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
```

But how can I specify the type, **securitygroup**, etc. ?

Are they already stored in the `ami` ?

I have seen a solution using `boto3.resources("ec2")` which I have already tried, but then I can't properly run UnitTests on it.

Comment: actually I have taken a look at the docs in code. There are not listed all of the input parameters.. well  then my bad, thanks anyways

Comment: Unclear what you mean with "docs in code", I would recommend using this as your reference: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.run_instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add the parameter `SecurityGroupIds` if you want to add one or more by the ID or `SecurityGroups` if you want to add by the name of the security group. Both of these should be of type `list`.

```py
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
client.run_instances(ImageId='ami-0df63501d4a3233e8', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1,
                     SecurityGroupIds=['sg-000000000000000'])
```

Replace `sg-000000000000000` with your real security group ID.